# kramdown coderay syntax_highlighter on jekyll ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I am doing **jekyll serve** and there are red marks.
How will I make these disappear:

```
Deprecation: Please change 'use_coderay' to 'enable_coderay' in your configuration file.

Deprecation: You are using 'kramdown.coderay' in your configuration, please use 'syntax_highlighter_opts' instead.
```

In my config file, I already have these lines:

```
kramdown:
  auto_ids: true
  footnote_nr: 1
  entity_output: as_char
  toc_levels: 1..6
  use_coderay: enable_coderay
```

Comment: Can you post all of your config file? The first error should be fixed by changing `use_coderay: enable_coderay` to `enable_coderay: true`

Answer (score 0):

```
enable_coderay         : true  
syntax_highlighter     : coderay  
syntax_highlighter_opts: {}
```

Comment: Add more desc text please

Answer (score -1):

Use `syntax_highlighter: rouge` as error clearly says *kramdown.coderay* is deprecated:

`Deprecation: You are using 'kramdown.coderay' in your configuration, please use 'syntax_highlighter_opts' instead.`

Comment: You have not provided any specific solution.